# Retrieving all cookies from IE using python

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I've been writing automated tests with Selenium Webdriver 2.45 in python.  To get through some of the things I need to test I must retrieve the various `JSESSION` cookies that are generate from the site.  When I use webdrivers `get_cookies()` function with Firefox or Chrome all of the needed cookies return to me.  When I do the same thing with IE11 I do not see the cookies that I need.  Anyone know how I can retrieve session cookies from IE?

Comment: Did you try the execute_script function of the driver to get cookies from JS? Like cookies=driver.execute_script("document.cookie")?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, it also doesn't return the JSESSION cookies

Answer (score 1):

What you describe sounds like an issue I ran into a few months ago. My tests ran fine with Chrome and Firefox but not in IE, and the problem was cookies. Upon investigation what I found is that my web site had set its session cookies to be [HTTP-only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly). When a cookie has this flag turned on, the browser will send the cookie over the HTTP(S) protocol and allow it to be set by the server in responses but it will make the cookie inaccessible to JavaScript. (Which is consistent with your comment that you cannot see the cookies you want in `document.cookie`.) It so happens that when you use Selenium with Chrome or Firefox, Selenium is able to ignore this flag and obtain the cookies from the browser anyway. However, it cannot do the same with IE.

I worked around this issue by turning off the HTTP-only flag when running my site in testing mode. I use Django for my server so I had to create a special `test_settings.py` file with `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False` in it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue with IE and Safari. Those driver will not return correct cookies information. At least not the domain. See [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8509)